# SCSS - adding variables in a loop

Tags: sass

In the block of code below I have to write it 6 times to change the `$blue` to a different colour. There must be an easier and more DRY way to write this code.

```
&:nth-child(1) {
  .fa-stack-1x { color: $white; }
  .fa-circle { color: $blue; }
  hr {
    background: $blue;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, $white, $blue, $white);
  }
  &:hover {
    background: $blue;
    .fa-stack-1x { color: $blue; }
    .fa-circle { color: $white; }
     a { 
       background-color: $white; 
       color: $blue; 
     }
     hr {
       background: $white;
       background-image: linear-gradient(to right, $blue, $white, $blue);
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, turns out its quite easy, and the below solves the problem

```
$colours-list: $blue, $burgundy, $green, $orange, $purple, $red;
@each $current-colour in $colours-list { 
  $i: index($colours-list, $current-colour);
    &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      .fa-stack-1x { color: $white; }
      .fa-circle { color: $current-colour; }
      hr {
        background: $current-colour;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, $white, $current-colour, $white);
      }
      a { background: $current-colour; color: $white; }
      &:hover {
        background: $current-colour;
        .fa-stack-1x { color: $current-colour; }
        .fa-circle { color: $white; }
        a { 
          background-colour: $white; 
          color: $current-colour; 
        }
        hr {
          background: $white;
          background-image: linear-gradient(to right, $current-colour, $white, $current-colour);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```